Woher weiß man, ob das Reflexivpronomen im Dativ oder Akkusativ steht?
Ich wollte wissen, ob das Pronomen bei sich begnügen mit im Dativ oder Akkusativ steht. Das heißt, ist es

Ich begnüge mich mit seiner Antwort.

oder

Ich begnüge mir mit seiner Antwort.

Meines Erachtens muss es die erste Wahl sein, denn die zweite klingt sehr komisch. Dies ist immerhin eine Frage, die mit einem Wörterbuch zu beantworten wäre, aber bisher habe ich das nicht machen können.  Wenn ich bei DWDS nachschlage, sehe ich

GrammatikVerb · reflexiv begnügt sich, begnügte sich, hat sich begnügt
sich mit etw. zufriedengeben, etw. nicht mehr verlangen
Beispiele:
sich mit wenigem begnügen / man muss lernen, sich zu begnügen / er
begnügte sich damit, von ferne zuzusehen

Ähnlich ist es bei Duden, usw.
Im Allgemeinen: wie weiß man bei reflexiven Verben, ob das Pronomen im Akkusativ oder Dativ steht?  Ist es anzunehmen, wenn es nichts anderes sagt, dass das Pronomen im Akkusativ steht?  D.h., wenn es im Dativ steht, würde das immer erwähnt?

In diesem speziellen Beispiel könnte man es an der Vorsilbe "be-" ablesen, die nach meinem Sprachgefühl stark auf ein transitives Verb hindeutet.

Du hast da wirklich eine Lücke angesprochen. Bei dwds.de stehen zwar oft viele Verwendungsbeispiele, aber es ist nicht garantiert, dass man dann sieht, wie es geht, weil zB das Pronomen "uns" auch nicht zwischen Dativ und Akkusativ unterscheidet! "Wir begnügen uns..." Tja. Man bräuchte die erste oder zweite Person im Singular, aber solche Beispiele gibt es auf der Seite für das Verb "begnügen" einfach nicht.
Das LEO-Wörterbuch gibt allerdings immer den Kasus des Reflexivs an: https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/begn%C3%BCgen
Äußerlich ablesen kann man es wohl nur, wenn Verben bereits ein Akkusativobjekt haben und daneben ein Reflexiv: Dann ist klar, dass das Reflexiv ein Dativ sein muss: "Er bildet sich das(-Akk) nur ein." (-- PS: Der Kommentar unten hat auch hierzu ein Gegenbeispiel, denn es gibt im Deutschen ein paar Verben mit 2 Akkusativen...)
Du deutest an, dass vielleicht das Akkusativ-Reflexiv der "normalere" Fall ist – das kann ich mir auch vorstellen, ich habe aber jetzt beim Nachlesen in Grammatiken keine Angaben über Häufigkeiten gefunden. Akkusativ könnte häufiger sein, weil einige Regeln über Entsprechungen zwischen Konstruktionen existieren, die ein Akkusativ-sich einführen:

Alternierende Verben haben das Reflexiv im Akkusativ: "Das wunderte ihn - Er wunderte sich(-Akk) darüber"; "Er öffnete die Türe – Die Türe öffnete sich(-Akk)".

Konstruktionen mit resultativem Adjektiv können ein bedeutungsleeres sich-Akkusativobjekt einführen, wenn das Resultat vom Subjekt ausgesagt werden soll: "Ich lache mich tot"; "Er isst sich satt"



PS: Hier ist ein lustiger Blogeintrag vom Institut für Deutsche Sprache, wo sie erzählen, dass sie erst selber nicht wussten, ob es beim Verb "sich behelfen" heißt: "ich behelfe mich mit etwas" oder "ich behelfe mir mit etwas": https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/4248  Das Ergebnis der Nachforschungen ist, dass es beides gibt.

Gute Antwort! Mir ist aber aufgefallen, dass selbst die Regel mit dem Akkusativobjekt mit "ich traue mich das nicht" eine Ausnahme hat...

Kleiner, partieller Hinweis: Mit der Internetseite Linguee ist oft ACC. oder DAT. erwähnt...
Zum Beispiel, lass uns "sich waschen" nachsuchen:
https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/sich+waschen.html
Es sagt: "sich(Akk) waschen"

Im Fall von waschen genügt es zu wissen, dass das Verb in nichtreflexiver Verwendung transitiv ist. Dadurch ist klar, dass das Reflexivpronomen den Akkusativ stehen muss. Schwierig wird es bei Verben, die ausschließlich reflexiv verwendet werden.

Das Reflexivpronomen (bzw. sein Ersatz, siehe unten) steht immer im Akkusativ. Das ist bei allen reflexiven Verben so, nicht nur bei sich begnügen.

ich begnüge mich
du begnügst dich
er/sie/es begnügt sich

etc..
Das einzige, was man sich bei reflexiven Verben merken muß, ist, daß bei manchen im Plural nicht der Akkusativ des Reflexivpronomens ("uns", "euch", "sich") sondern "einander" gebraucht wird - nämlich dann, wenn eine Handlung wechselseitig vollzogen wird:

wir treffen uns

das geht zwar, aber nur bei einem Duell mit Schußwaffen. Wenn wir lediglich auf der Straße zusammentreffen, dann ist das

wir treffen einander

Ebenso:

Wir kämmen uns.

Da kämme ich mich und du dich. Hingegen

Wir kämmen einander.

Da kämmst du mich und ich dich.

Du meinst: Wenn das Reflexiv das einzige Objekt ist, ist es immer Akkusativ? Das vermute ich auch, aber haben wir einen Beleg dafür? Die Dudengrammatik (2022, § 1112) sagt nichts darüber, obwohl die Beispiele danach aussehen.

@Alazon: abgesehen davon, daß der Duden keine Autorität hat und die Art und Weise, wie die Dudenredaktion zu Schlüssen kommt, als Geschäftsgeheimnis betrachtet wird (was genaugenommen bedeutet, daß er zumindest sprachwissenschaftlich keine reputable Quelle darstellt) - davon abgesehen ergibt die Betrachtung der Entstehung des Reflexivums, daß es sich bei dem Pronomen nur um einen Kasus Obliquus handeln kann. Der aber ist auf Deutsch immer der Akkusativ.

Ich wollte auch erwähnen, dass sprachgeschichtlich die Verwendung von "sich" im Dativ eine Neuerung ist, aber das erklärt nichts, denn man hatte vorher halt reflexive Verben mit Dativ-Personalpronomen, etwa Frühneuhochdeutsch: "Er setzete ihm vor, dass..." (= Gegenwartsdeutsch: "Er nahm sich(-Dat) vor...")

Ich nehme mir morgen frei und bin mit mir im Reinen.

Ich stelle mir vor, dass es da auch Ausnahmen geben könnte.

@JonathanHerrera: ich stelle mir vor, daß nur ich stelle mich vor als Reflexivum gilt. "ich nehme mir frei", "ich bin mit mir im Reinen" und dgl. sind - wenigstens in meinen Augen - nicht reflexiv, sondern "normale" Objektfälle. Was soll denn der Unterschied zwischen "ich nehme mir frei" und "ich gebe dir ein Brot" sein? Zweiteres ist transitiv, aber nicht reflexiv - und das ist ersteres auch.

Witzig, "ich nehme ihm frei".

"Sich freinehmen" ist jetzt das erste Gegenbeispiel, wo ein Dativ-Reflexiv nicht neben einer anderen Ergänzung steht. Damit ist meine Vermutung aus dem ersten Kommentar im Grundsatz widerlegt. – Es scheint aber, bei der Diskussion gehts nur um inhärente Reflexive, also Reflexivverben, sollte man dazusagen...

@bakunin Bei sich vorstellen ("imaginieren") ist nur das Subjekt auch als Objekt möglich - in dem Sinne ist das Verb "reflexiv". Die These, dass reflexive Verben nur mit dem Akkusativ stehen, müsste auf einer trennscharfen Definition von "reflexives Verb" fußen, die diese Fälle unterscheidet. Ich kenne eine solche Definition (noch) nicht. Wenn du sie kennst, wäre es sehr hilfreich, sie in der Antwort zu erwähnen. Dann hättest du zugleich das Kriterium formuliert, nach dem OP fragt. Es wäre auch sehr hilfreich für Sprachlerner, dieses Kriterium explizit zu haben.

Diese Definition sollte sich idealwerweise gerade nicht daran festmachen, dass das Pronomen im Akkusativ steht, um zu vermeiden, dass die Erklärung zirkulär wird. Wenn das gelingt, wäre mein Verständnis der Sache deutlich erweitert.

@DavidVogt : bin mit mir im Reinen passt nicht als Beispiel, da wir hier keine Reflexivität haben. Es ist ja eine Präposition "mit" dabei. Ich könnte auch mit meiner Umwelt im Reinen sein.

Ich lasse mir Zeit. Ich nehme mir Zeit. Ich leiste mir etwas. Ich wünsche mir etwas. Ich gebe mir Mühe. Ich mache mir Sorgen. Ich merke mir etwas.
